# Where to find Entries into an Index on CRSP (WRDS)

Tags: index, crsp

I am trying to find index entry events (not delisting events) on CRSP (i.e., when a specific stock with a PERMNO/CUSIP enters the S&P500), but despite trawling through the documentation I am unable to find this data. Several academic (finance) papers suggest that CRSP does indeed have this data. Would anybody be so kind as to shed light on where I can find it?

Comment: This shows one way to do it (although I have not tested it) https://bizlib247.wordpress.com/2016/06/02/getting-sp-500-constituents-from-crsp-via-wrds-cloud-using-ssh-and-sas/